# Perfect forwarding template parameter pack to emplace_back - failed compilation

Tags: templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Apologies if there is a solution in a similar question, I was unable to find one with similar error output / problem.

I am attempting to compile this code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template< typename value_type >
class obj
{
    vector<value_type> m_v;
  public:

    template<class... vaList_t>
    void _emplace_back(vaList_t&&... i_values)
    {
        m_v.emplace_back( forward<vaList_t>(i_values)... );
    }
};

int main()
{
  obj<int> thing;
  thing._emplace_back(1,2,3,4);
  return 0;
}
```

However it fails to compile with:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:61,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = int; _Args = {int, int, int, int}; _Tp = int]':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:253:4:   required from 'static std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = int; _Args = {int, int, int, int}; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> = void]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:399:57:   required from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = int; _Args = {int, int, int, int}; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/vector.tcc:97:40:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int, int, int, int}; _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]'
13:3:   required from 'void obj<value_type>::_emplace_back(vaList_t&& ...) [with vaList_t = {int, int, int, int}; value_type = int]'
20:30:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Questions:

- Is this syntactically correct for perfect forwarding a template parameter pack? (if not what is?)
- What is the correct way of achieving this behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
Sorry for any ambiguity. I am trying to call this vector function called emplace_back with type signature:

```
template< class... Args > void emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

with a perfect forwarded, template parameter pack which contains multiple elements to be added.

eg:

- "1,2,3,4" - add 4 different objects to the back of the vector via
  emplace_back
- "true,false,false" - add 3 different objects to the back of the vector via emplace_back

Comment: Perhaps you mean `m_v.insert(m_v.end(), { forward<vaList_t>(i_values)... });`, or, `(m_v.emplace_back(forward<vaList_t>(i_values)), ...);`

Comment: You want to insert 4 items to the vector?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki the ",..." does not compile. the insert does compile. However it ins't perfect forwarding the parameter pack? The function arguments for insert are an iterator and an initialization list, thus incurs additional overhead?

Comment: @kennytm Nope, I want to use the inner object's (this case vector) emplace_back function to emplace elements that have been forwarded from a template parameter pack.

Comment: @QuantumKarl But you can't construct an `int` with `int, int, int, int`. The value_type needs to accept `int, int, int, int` as argument for this compile, e.g. `value_type == std::tuple<int, int, int, int>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`c.emplace_back` creates a *single* element in `c`. If you want multiple ones, you'll need to make `emplace_back` part of the expansion. Something like this:

```
template<class... vaList_t>
void _emplace_back(vaList_t&&... i_values)
{
    int dummy[] = { 0, (m_v.emplace_back(forward<vaList_t>(i_values)), 0)... };
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10bbb9006dc6c44e)

Comment: Thank you. I see now: "Appends a new element to the end of the container." (the template parameter version is for objects with multiple arguments, note multiple objects).

Comment: @QuantumKarl Exactly. The true power of `emplace_back` over `push_back` is that it allows you to construct the element directly in the container (instead of copying/moving it in) by passing the constructor arguments all the way down.

Comment: Looks like this is using the comma operator to make the emplace_back a side effect of the expansion? Ugly, but useful :).